# Sine offset of Vertices based on Position/Normal not Index

Tags: mesh, vertices, geometry-nodes, mathematics

I am working on a Geometry Node System that can turn every simple mesh into cardboard with the infamous wave curve between both flat borders. I use the sine function for that and have a complicated problem on what to put into it:

My first approach was index-based. By dividing the vertex index through the amount of vertices in each row and floor that number, I could get parallel ordered waves.
However I got random flips per face which was not desired.
[image]

My second approach was position-based. At first I used the x position of each vertex to drive the offset. No more flips per face, in general it works great.
[image]

But now I want to flip the direction of the wave pattern and use YZ instead of X and things get very complicated.I tried to just sum up the Y and Z positions but this leads to weird distortions and lack of consistency in the frequency of the pattern on diagonals.
[image]

I am sure I have to use the vertex normal as a factor here and plug that somehow into the equation. I can read it out per vertex with the Field at Index Node, but all tries have failed so far. Maybe the community knows the answer.

[Blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7tx8yp6sm18nhyz/AACSX2fk5pp3T8wO-dpQc4ONa?dl=0)

Have a nice day
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you should use UVmap to get this right.

[image]

It's much easier and controllable. And of course it will work with animation.

Comment: I'm a retard. Thanks for reminding me of that ;). This works